# Storing a DynamicLMClassifier (Lingpipe)

Tags: java, nlp

I'm using lingpipe for sentiment analysis (following [this](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/demos/tutorial/sentiment/src/PolarityBasic.java) code) and I am trying to store the classifier after I train it. The problem is that after storing it I can't load it:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: com.aliasi.classify.LMClassifier cannot be cast to com.aliasi.classify.DynamicLMClassifier`

For storing the classifier I use:

```
AbstractExternalizable.compileTo(mClassifier, classifierFile);
```

and for loading it:

```
mClassifier = (DynamicLMClassifier<NGramProcessLM>) AbstractExternalizable.readObject(classifierFile);
```

Edit:
I should have read the lingpipe's javadoc before. To store the classifier and load it afterwards the `mClassifier`'s class should be `LMClassifier<NGramProcessLM, MultivariateEstimator>`. Thus it can be initialized to be a [`DynamicLMClassifier<NGramProcessLM>`](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/docs/api/com/aliasi/classify/DynamicLMClassifier.html#compileTo%28java.io.ObjectOutput%29) and during the training phase it is necessary to cast it to `DynamicLMClassifier<NGramProcessLM>`. After this it can be loaded and used to classify new objects. As @mjv said this makes the classifier no longer trainable.

Answer (score 1):

The AbstractExternalizable.compileTo() method merely invokes the compileTo() method of the object being serialized and sends the output to the file specified.

Since the [**DynamicLMClassifier.compileTo()**](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/docs/api/com/aliasi/classify/DynamicLMClassifier.html#compileTo%28java.io.ObjectOutput%29) method produces a `LMClassifier` that's what you get when you deserialize.  A LMClassifier is pretty much the same thing, if anything, more efficient and compact, the main difference is that it is not trainable;  this is therefore only a problem if you intend to keep training the classifier after its initial creation.

If you need to keep training the classifier, you can serialize the LanguageModels separately (most LanguageModels implement Compilable), and recreate the dynamic classifier by invoking its constructor and passing it the list of deserialized models.  I've never tried this approach, but I believe this is the recommended way, particularly now that the serialization of LingPipe objects has been refactored.

Comment: This is not my case, but what if I would have intended to keep training the classifier after compiling it?

Comment: @miguel for repeated dynamic training you can persist the LanguageModels instead.  (See my edit)